# using jedis hmset method for inserting multiple field element in redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am implementing a simple redis command using jedis in java.  The redis-cli command is:

```
hmset myhash key "value1" field2 "value2" field3 "value3"
```

The problem is that `jedis`'s `hmset` method requires two parameters:

- `String key`
- `Map <String, String> hash`

Possible solution:

```
String key;
String value2;
String value3;
while(!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
    key = someQueue.poll()
    value2 = getTitle(key)
    value3 = getSize(value2)
    jedis.hmset(key, value2Map)
    jedis.hmset(key, value3Map)
...
```

But it feels a bit counter-intuitive having to implement three Tree Map objects to get their last added object in order to add a tuple with three fields in the redis db.

Just hoping for some better ideas before going ahead and implementing this.

Comment: I have update my question to be a bit more clear.  I have not created the maps yet - i ' m in the process of doing so now.  But they will be NavigableMap in order to be able to get the last entry while performing the loop.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing in using hmset? I think you can simply create k map of your key values and store that map in hmset with a key for identification of that map. Rest, if you'll state the issue then better I can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are looking for but I think you need to put all values into a hashmap and place the hashmap object in jedis.hmset() as a second param. See below

```
Map<String, String> avalue = new 
HashMap<String, String>();
avalue.put(a, a1);
avalue.put(b, b1);
avalue.put(c, c1);
avalue.put(d,d1)
jedis.hmset(key, avalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) if you looking Java API compatible solution:

```
Map<String, String> redisMap = redisson.getMap("myMap");

Map<String, String> newEntries = new HashMap<>();
newEntries.put("1", "a");
newEntries.put("2", "b");
newEntries.put("3", "c");

redisMap.putAll(newEntries);
```